# ¿Cómo asignar valores a un objeto vacío en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo un objeto vacío, como ser `let obj = {}` cómo hago para insertar las clave valor `1:2`, para que el objeto quede así: `obj = {1:2}` ??

y si luego quiero insertar otro par clave valor cómo lo hago??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fácilmente puedes hacerlo así:

```js
let obj = {};
obj[1] = 2; // [1] es la clave, "2" es el valor.
console.log(obj);
```

Y si quieres agregar más valores, sería algo así:

```js
let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  obj[i] = i;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

usando `Object.defineProperty()`, ahi te deje un enlace a la documentacion de MDN docs del metodo:

```
let obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "1", { value: 2 });
console.log(obj)
```

[Documentacion MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

sino podes hacer simplemente:

```
obj.property = "value"
console.log(obj)
```

el problema de esto es que no podes poner obj.1 = "2", el 1 como atributo te dara error de sintaxis, pero con cualquier nombre que no sea un numero sirve.